# Heaven's authorities reject person and revive instead

Tags: ideas, mythology, death

I have this specific issue I am trying to work out:

Each time this one particular person dies on planet Earth as he ends up in heaven and from there reaches the authorities, they tell him they can not keep him for a "some reason" and have to send him back. This eventually doesn't end until he gets really old and dies just from age when they finally let him stay.

Now the question is why would the authorities of heaven not allow him to stay in the first and all further situations? What reason might there be for just a single person in human history?

When he dies he remembers everything and when they resurrect him he also remembers everything. Wgen he is resurrected he returns to his body which would always be in good condition and undamaged even if he fell of a tall building onto the ground. The authorities always remember him and tell the very same reason as the first time.

Comment: I'm sorry, but questions about how your plot should develop are off-topic here as well. WorldBuilding.SE shouldn't have redirected you here.

Comment: If he remembers everything, they probably wouldn't tell him the reason since it might change him. It doesn't seem to have any impact on his life – or the story – if he can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 3):

*And somewhere between the time you arrive
And the time you go
May lie a reason you were alive
That you'll never know*
 - Jackson Browne - "For A Dancer"

Your character must have a very important task to perform near the end of his life.  Something subtle, yet critical to the master plan.  Perhaps, in his decrepitude, he will be sitting on a park bench watching pigeons when a little girl offers him a flower.  That gift of a flower might be the first generous act of a child who is destine to teach great kindness to a world that desperately needs her teachings.  By accepting the flower with gratitude and respect, your character starts her on her critical path.  If he hadn't been on that bench at just that moment, and responded just the way his hard life had prepared him to, she would have taken a less kind path in her own life and the world would be much less for the change.   Your heavenly authorities can explain all that too him as he petitions the pearly gates for the final (successful) time.

Comment: Wow, that leads me to great thoughts. You are a genius. Seriously, you have made me feel too responsible for my character.